# UTF character codes

Tags: javascript, encoding

I am using this script:

```
  document.write("ð".charCodeAt(0));
```

It gives me 240.

Where can I obtain a number to represent a number such as 251?

Where do i get the unicode numbers from?

Comment: what do you want?
can you be more specific?

Comment: [The first hit](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=256) when googling with the header of your question...

Comment: JavaScript support for multi-byte escapes is terrible.

Comment: Also this really doesn't make sense: *Where can I obtain a number to represent a number such as 251?*

Answer (score 0):

a) Stop using document.write(), you're not meant to use it. If you need to put things on your page, find the element it goes in, and set its innerHTML, or create an element, add it to your body, then set that element's innerHTML. Or use alert() or console.log().

b) charCodeAt will give you higher unicode values just fine.

```
"ð".charCodeAt(0) -> 240
"ð".charCodeAt(0).toString(16) -> "f0"

"日本語".charCodeAt(0) -> 26085
"日本語".charCodeAt(0).toString(16) -> "65e5"
```

Works fine.